# Is it possible for a ListView control to display multiple colums?

Tags: asp.net, listview

Is it possible for the `ListView` control to display n columns wide, rather than just in a single column list?

By this, I don't mean different properties belong to an item, but items both across and down.

Comment: Check out [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.aspx). Specifically, the [LayoutTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.layouttemplate.aspx) and ItemTemplate aspects. I believe this will provide the flexibility that you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a ListView, using templates, will render multiple fields easily while retaining its differentiator, support for per item commands.  See the MSDN documentation for ListView.ItemTemplate.

Comment: I actually want to display the same field across and down rather than multiple fields from the same row.

Comment: That is a matter of html + css, not asp.net.  The asp.net bits are to use the template feature I pointed out.  For the comic book layout (across and down) there are many examples on the web.  Myspace's redesign comes to mind, but it's just an example.